# Building a window application from the bunch of python files

Tags: python, file, window

I have written some bunch of python files  and i want to make a window application from that. 
The structure looks like this:
Say, a.py,b.py,c.py are there. a.by is the file which i want application to open and it is basically a  GUI which has import commands for "b.py" and "c.py". 
I know this might be a very basic problem,but i have just started to packaging and deployment using python.Please tell me how to do that , or if is there any way to do it by py2exe and pyinstaller?

I have tried to do it by py2exe and pyinstaller from the info available on internet , but that seems to create the app which is running only "a.py" .It is not able to then use "b" and "c " as well.

Answer (score 1):

### Python at least 3.5 - `zipapp`

Assuming this is your project tree,

```
<root_folder>
    | - a.py
    | - b.py
    | - c.py
```

you can rename `a.py` to `__main__.py` and then call from bash/cmd `python -m zipapp <root_folder>` in order to create a `<root_folder>.pyz` file.

This file is executable both with Windows and UNIX systems, and will package every module that lies inside your `<root_folder>`.

If you need to include libraries too, you have to call `python -m pip install <libs> --target <root_folder>` and, after, you call `zipapp` like shown above.

This is the [documentation of `zipapp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html).

---

### Python at least 2.6 - `zipfile`

Since Python 2.6, you can create a zip file containing all your files (and `__main__.py` too, cause it's your entry point) and then run it in console launching

```
python <zip_name>.zip
```

Pay attention: your zip has to be structured like this

```
<zip_name>.zip
    | - __main__.py
    | - b.py
    | - c.py
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply crissal,but i am using python 2.7.13 :(  . Is there any way to do that in py2.7

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on how you do this with py2exe. I have used py2app before which is very similar, but it is for Mac applications. For Mac there is a way to view the contents of the application. In here you can add the files you want into the resources folder (where you would put your 'b.py' and 'c.py').

I hope there is something like this in Windows and hope it helps.